# ESC commands to print barcode to a thermal printer?

Tags: java, arrays, printing, barcode, thermal-printer

When you purchase a thermal receipt printer, you also get a manual that tells you which byte sequence should be used to do what (cutting, finishing job, setting fonts etc). However I do not have an understanding of Java that is sufficient for me to be able to use the ESC/POS commands.

I have a Citizen CT S2000 thermal receipt printer. I have already managed to use the byte sequences for cutting and line feeding and manipulating what fonts the thermal printer is supposed to have. However I can not figure out how to use the ESC commands for generating and printing barcode.

The manual on how to do this is [here](http://www.citizen-systems.com/sites/default/files/CommandReference015E_120607_4.pdf#page=26&zoom=auto,57,791) on page 144. Here a sample code is provided in BASIC.

```
LPRINT CHR$(&H1D);"k"; CHR$(73); CHR$(10);
LPRINT "{BNo.{C"; CHR$(12); CHR$(34); CHR$(56);
LPRINT CHR$(&HA);
END
```

Here is my attempt to print the barcode.

```
public static void barcode() throws Exception{
    byte[] b = {0x7b, 0x43, 0x12, 0x34}; 
    //This is the commands as I interpreted the to print out 12 and 34

    DocPrintJob job = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().createPrintJob();

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE; 
    /*This is how I send byte sequences. 
    if you got something better then don't hesitate yelling at me :D : ). */

    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(b, flavor, null);

    job.print(doc, null);                   
}
```

Yet this does not yield anything at all and the printer doesn't do anything at all.

I really can't find any examples of how to do it.

Any answers/comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at JavaPOS: http://www.javapos.com/samplecode.html. You probably have to install drivers for it though (for Epson there is a JavaPOS ADK), but once you got it working, it's a nice library to work with.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely check it out. But is it really necessary to install drivers ? I was able to get some other commands such as the cut command working.

Comment: I'm not sure. I implemented something similar, but this was for an Epson Printer, and this would not work without installing Epson JavaPOS drivers .

Comment: Well since I was able to prompt the printer do to other commands I't seems unlikely that I need to install anything else to be able to use it. The question at hand seems to be what the proper syntax is for the ESC commands shown in Java.

Comment: I was able to simply send a String to printer, and using unicode characters in them for the Esc commands. For example, I could use `"\u001b|fP"` for the paper cut command.

Comment: Well how would you do it if the ESC code if the <1D>H<6B>H<<n>[d1...dn]

Comment: I guess I'm missing the obvious or something. I just really think that it is frustrating since no examples are provided. If you can give me an answer with an example in Java i will thumb it up and mark it as the correct answer : )

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command you can print the barcode.

```
byte[] barCode = {0x1d,0x6b,0x07,0x6e,0x61,0x72};

Here 0x6e,0x61,0x72 are the charters "nar" which converted into barcode.
```

I'm sure it will work. Please let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Does this answer make any sense?

Comment: However I can not figure out how to use the ESC commands for generating and printing barcode.
@DilaGurung if you see above lines mentioned in the question and then try the answer given by me that you automatically realise that it makes sense. :)